# what is happening when we use object reference in c#? Is it similar object referencing in JAVA

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

Given the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program : abstrct, interfc        {

        abstrct obj = new Program(); // whats happening here
        interfc obj2 = new Program();//is it creating  object of interfc?    
        public override void add()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public void sub()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public abstract class abstrct
    {
        public void  program2()
        {
        }
        public abstract void add();
    }
    interface interfc
    {
        public void sub();
    }
       }
```

What is an object reference?
  abstrct obj = new Program();
can i access all the methods of Program class using obj;

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please clarify what your question is and what the problem is. `it showing error` doesn't tell us anything. Compile error? Runtime exception? What is the error/exception? Indicate where exactly in your code it is happening. Did you google the error/exception to try to understand what it is and why it's happening? Any effort to fix it so far?

Comment: its not showing any error but i want to know whats happening when we write the object refernces..

Comment: Eh? You say multiple times in your post that there are errors. Ignoring or being dishonest about errors clearly present (and looking at your code, there *has* to be errors) will not make them go away. You need to make compilable code before we can tell you what it does. Code that doesn't compile doesn't do *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't support multiple class inheritance.  `Program` is not allowed to extend multiple classes, and you're trying to have it extend `abstrct` and `baseclass`.  That's not allowed.

Since `Program` is not *actually* extending `baseclass`, you cannot implicitly convert it to `baseclass`.  If you create a class that *actually* extends `baseclass` then the implicit conversion will work.

Answer (score 1):

It will create objects of type Program. But you var is of a base type, you will only be able to access the base members.

The main problem is that c# is a single inheritance language, so you cannot inherit from abstrct and baseclass simultaneously. Also the class inherited from must come first in the inheritence list. This compiles fine, but obviously blows up due to the recursive instantiations.

```
class Program : baseclass, interfc
{
    interfc onj2 = new Program();//is it creating object object of interfc?
    baseclass b = new baseclass();
    baseclass b2 = new Program();  // why its showing error here

    public void sub()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public abstract class abstrct
{
    public void  program2()
    {
    }
    public abstract void add();
}
interface interfc
{
    void sub();
}

class baseclass
{
  public void div()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("base class method");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, C# doesn't support multiple inheritance. You can't inherit `Program` from `AbstractClass` and `BaseClass` simultaneously.

Secondly, you cannot specify an access modifier in an interface declaration. All members are public implicitly.

You can't create an object of interface or abstract class. It's a fundamental principle of OOP.

You can however create a reference to an object with an interface type or a base class type.

More correct code and comments are here:

```
    class Program : AbstractClass, Interface//, BaseClass
    {
        AbstractClass obj = new Program();
        //creating object of Program class and store reference to them in obj variable with AbstractClass type -> have access to program2() and add()

        Interface onj2 = new Program();
        //creating object of Program class and store reference to them in obj2 variable with Interface type -> have access to sub() only

        BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
        //just create object of BaseClass class

        //BaseClass b2 = new Program();
        //it is imposible, Program not IS BaseClass here

        public override void add()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public void sub()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    public abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        public void program2()
        {
        }
        public abstract void add();
    }
    interface Interface
    {
        void sub();
    }
    class BaseClass
    {
        public void div()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("base class method");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: storing refernece to tem in obj.i need to know more about this...i have confusion in this area

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question (after the updates) correctly, then the answer is *yes, sort of*.

What you are basically asking is, if you create an instance of a child class but declare its type to be a base class/interface, can you still access all of the child class's members,

That is, given the following interface and classes:

```
public interface IBase 
{
   void A();
}

public class Parent
{
  public void B();
}

public class Child : Parent, IBase
{
  public void A();
  public void C();
}
```

Can you do the following:

```
IBase a = new Child();
a.C();

Parent b = new Child();
b.C();
```

No, neither of those calls to `C()` will compile. What is happening here is that the *compile-time* type of those identifiers is the type that you explicitly declared them to be, in this case, `IBase` and `Parent`. From that point on, the compiler will assume that you want it to validate all of your uses of those identifiers for correctness based on those types.  Since neither `IBase` nor `Parent` has a method `C()`, you cannot call that method on objects of those types.

But, you can do this:

```
IBase a = new Child();
(a as Child).C();

Parent b = new Child();
(b as Child).C();
```

Because, at run time, the *actual instance* that gets created in both cases is really a `Child` object; if you asked `a` or `b` for their type at run-time, using `GetType()`, they would correctly report that they were `Child` objects. The `as` keyword (or, if you prefer, the typecast operator) instructs the compiler to change the compile-type type of an identifier to something else, on the assumption that *you*, the developer, has made sure that change is safe. If `a` really is a `Child`, then `(a as Child)` will work. If `a` were some other class, then `(a as Child)` results in a `null`, and the next line would fail *at run-time*.